# What is more objectionable to Christians: Satanism or Atheism?

Tags: satan, atheism

What does the Christian religion find more objectionable: the worship of Satan, or the non-belief in a God.

Comment: It's important to note that Satanists consists of (very few) people who accept Satan's existence, worship him, maybe eat babies and whatnot (this is more commonly an accusation by Christians, especially historically), but also consists of people who view Satan as a metaphorical figurehead to oppose Christianity, and commonly the harm it does. Also, atheism includes those who are uncertain (agnostic atheist), and those who are certain that no gods exist, they may or may not have heard of Christianity, and may or may not try to convince others of their position. All that shouldn't be conflated.

Answer (score 6):

One would have to make some sort of survey to answer the question regarding the two alternatives offered, by the question, regarding Christians.

To my own mind, it is clear what Jesus Christ's values were in that his most vigorous and his most comprehensive censuring was against **neither of the above but against hypocrisy.** I can think of no stronger words which he uttered on this earth which were so condemnatory against particular characteristics.

Jesus of Nazareth pronounced an eight fold 'Woe' (a witness to the four corners of the earth) against the leaders of religion, in the days of his flesh upon earth, which leaders held the outward positions of religious power over the people yet rejected the real kingdom of heaven, selfishly coveting their own power and their own position despite that it was sheer hypocrisy for them to maintain it in the face of the witness of both John the Baptist and Jesus of Nazareth to their falsity and their greed and their covetousness :

> But woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye shut up the kingdom of heaven against men: for ye neither go in yourselves, neither suffer ye them that are entering to go in.
>
> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye devour widows' houses, and for a pretence make long prayer: therefore ye shall receive the greater damnation.
>
> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye compass sea and land to make one proselyte, and when he is made, ye make him twofold more the child of hell than yourselves.
>
> Woe unto you, ye blind guides, which say, Whosoever shall swear by the temple, it is nothing; but whosoever shall swear by the gold of the temple, he is a debtor! 17Ye fools and blind: for whether is greater, the gold, or the temple that sanctifieth the gold? 18And, Whosoever shall swear by the altar, it is nothing; but whosoever sweareth by the gift that is upon it, he is guilty. 19Ye fools and blind: for whether is greater, the gift, or the altar that sanctifieth the gift? 20Whoso therefore shall swear by the altar, sweareth by it, and by all things thereon. 21And whoso shall swear by the temple, sweareth by it, and by him that dwelleth therein. 22And he that shall swear by heaven, sweareth by the throne of God, and by him that sitteth thereon.
>
> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye pay tithe of mint and anise and cummin, and have omitted the weightier matters of the law, judgment, mercy, and faith: these ought ye to have done, and not to leave the other undone. 24Ye blind guides, which strain at a gnat, and swallow a camel.
>
> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye make clean the outside of the cup and of the platter, but within they are full of extortion and excess. 26Thou blind Pharisee, cleanse first that which is within the cup and platter, that the outside of them may be clean also.
>
> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye are like unto whited sepulchres, which indeed appear beautiful outward, but are within full of dead men's bones, and of all uncleanness. 28Even so ye also outwardly appear righteous unto men, but within ye are full of hypocrisy and iniquity.
>
> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! because ye build the tombs of the prophets, and garnish the sepulchres of the righteous, 30And say, If we had been in the days of our fathers, we would not have been partakers with them in the blood of the prophets. 31Wherefore ye be witnesses unto yourselves, that ye are the children of them which killed the prophets. 32Fill ye up then the measure of your fathers.
>
> Ye serpents, ye generation of vipers, how can ye escape the damnation of hell?

[Matthew 23 : 13-23 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/matthew/23.htm)

Answer (score 4):

I would argue for **atheism**.

Satanists are certainly opposed to God... but they recognize that God, or at least Satan, exists. "You believe that God is one; you do well. Even the demons believe—and shudder!" (James 2:19)

Many atheists are *adamantly* opposed to Christianity and are quite zealous to convince Christians that God-belief is delusional... when it is they themselves that are deluded. "<sup>18</sup>For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who by their unrighteousness suppress the truth. <sup>19</sup>For what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has shown it to them. <sup>20</sup>For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal power and divine nature, have been clearly perceived, ever since the creation of the world, in the things that have been made. So they are without excuse." (Romans 1) "<sup>10</sup>...they refused to love the truth and so be saved. <sup>18</sup>Therefore God sends them a strong delusion, so that they may believe what is false..." (2 Thessalonians 2)

Both groups oppose God and promote all manner of evil. Both proselytize... but the persecution from atheists is, in my experience, more vicious, and their denial of Truth more complete.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends somewhat on  the type of atheism and the type of Satanism. However, Satanism has little intellectual or moral power and is not a great threat either to Christianity or the world. Atheism, however, especially militant atheism, has done great harm and continues to be a real threat. Some forms of Satanism are bizarre and meant to offend Christians, but atheism is more objectionable because it poses a more serious challenge and threat.

There are several [branches or forms of Satanism](https://www.learnreligions.com/laveyan-satanism-theistic-satanism-and-luciferianism-95715):

- **Devil-worshipers**. (Also known as "adolescent Satanists" because they tend to be unorganized teenagers who grow out of it.) They believe Satan is  an evil god, but one to be worshiped rather than shunned.
- **The Church of Satan**  In this religion, neither God nor Satan are actual beings; the only "god" is the Satanist himself.
- **Temple of Set**. A breakaway group from the Church of Satan this group worships a being sometimes called Satan, sometimes Set, based on the ancient Egyptian notion of "self-creation."
- **Luciferians** This group sees Lucifer is seen as a creature of enlightenment, the who brings light out of the darkness.
- The are several other religious groups and fads that fall into the general category of Satanism.

There are two main types of atheism:

- **Philosophical atheism**. This is simply the belief that God does not exist.
- **Militant atheism**. This seeks to impose its belief on others through the power of the state. The prime example of militant atheism is Marxism-Leninism.

**Conclusion**. In Christian belief, Satan is the prime force of evil and does tremendous harm. But Satan is probably not a Satanist. As C.S. Lewis taught in the *Screwtape Letters*, the greatest victory of the Devil world be to succeed in convincing humankind that God does not exist. Therefore, atheism is a greater threat to Christianity than Satanism, as the latter has never amounted to much and never will. Philosophical atheism at least respects the freedom of Christians to believe and organize as they wish. Militant atheism is the most objectionable of all, having ruled more than 1/3 of the world in the 20th century and still representing a powerful force in China, Cuba, North Korea, universities, and political parties throughout the world.

Comment: Militant atheism is also a powerful force in Europe, Canada, and (to a slightly lesser but growing extent) the US.

Comment: Yes... I was think of that when I mentioned universities and political parties

Answer (score 1):

In [Matthew 12:30 (ESV)](https://biblehub.com/matthew/12-30.htm), Jesus says "Whoever is not with me is against me, and whoever does not gather with me scatters."  This is in response to various people accusing him of being in league with demons, but, even out of that context, the message is clear: you're either actively supporting Jesus, or you're supporting a creed that is working against him.  Satanism and atheism are equally objectionable in principle, because the objectionable thing is not the details of the false belief but the fact that there is any belief contradictory to the word of God at all.

In practice, different Christian groups will at different times be more worried about one or the other.  Most non-Christian people I know are some variety of atheist, so the arguments I make in defense of my faith are usually tuned for that.  If you just listened to me talk to my friends, you'd assume I found atheism much worse than Satanism for that reason.  I would in fact be neither happy nor sad if my friends all suddenly became Satanists (although I would probably wonder what could possibly have caused this); what would make me happy is if they all became Christian.

(I'd also note that, since all efforts to frustrate Christianity are products of Satan, atheists are in one way just Satanists who don't know it yet!)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain differences between atheists and devil worshippers. Atheists do not have a motivator .They come together with identical ideologies and go public challenging the faithful. Devil worshippers have their motivator who pulls them back from accepting the True God. Since their activites are not accepted by the common public,they practise underground and are seldom seen imposing their ideologies on the public. Thus, looking from the point of spiritual safety of the Christian faithful, the group of Atheists appear to be more dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

**What is more objectionable to christians: satanism or atheism?**

The short answer is **satanism**.

[Atheism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheism) in its’ broadest sense, is an absence of belief in the existence of God. Atheism do not in itself preclude a genuine search for God’s existence.

Whereas followers of [Satanism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satanism) have Satan as their leader. A Demon who hates and desires to destroy everything the is Christian and holy!

Recall what St. James says about the Demon:

> Thou believest that there is one God; thou doest well. The devils also believe — and tremble. - [James 2:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/James%202%3A19)

Or St. Peter:

> Be alert and of sober mind. Your enemy the devil prowls around like a roaring lion looking for someone to devour. - [1 Peter 5:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%205%3A8&version=NIV)

Scriptures have many references to the Devil, Satan and the Demon try to ruin souls!

This is the leader of Satanism. Modern Satanism will wash down this point of view, but the reality remains in tack: Satan desires the ruin of the Kingdom of God.

If their is any doubt just ask an exorcist. The reality of [Black Masses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mass) still happens in modern times!

> The Catholic Archdiocese of Oklahoma on Thursday dropped a lawsuit filed a day earlier against a Satanic church after it turned over to a Catholic priest a consecrated host, or communion wafer, Satanists planned to use in a "black mass."
>
> "I am relieved that we have been able to secure the return of the sacred Host and that we have prevented its desecration as part of a planned Satanic ritual. I remain concerned about the dark powers that this satanic worship invites into our community and the spiritual danger that this poses to all who are involved in it, directly or indirectly," he said.
>
> A lawyer for the Angra Mainyu Satanic group named in the suit turned over the communion wafer on Thursday.
>
> The Catholic Archdiocese claimed the communion wafer was obtained "by illicit means." Adam Daniels, leader of Angra Mainyu, said the wafer was sent to him from a priest in Turkey who is also a Satanist.
>
> Daniels said the Angra Mainyu will instead use Black Forest bread from Germany in its ceremony, set for Sept. 21 at the Civic Center in Oklahoma City. The use of Black Forest bread, Daniels said, is a practice that dates back to the 1600s.
>
> The Black Mass of Oklahoma has been held for several years and has faced resistance from state and local leaders as well as setting off anger in a state where many identify themselves as deeply religious Christians.
>
> The black mass is a modern ritual to celebrate the perversion of the Catholic Mass, Angra Mainyu said. The group will also hold a Satanic exorcism, designed to drive out the "Holy Ghost" from a person, it said. - [Oklahoma Catholic bishop drops suit over planned 'black mass'](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-oklahoma-blackmass-idUSKBN0GM00Z20140822/)

All Satanist tend to target the Catholic Church often, other Christian denominations are targeted also.

Here follows a YouTube video on this subject matter:

- [A Dark Journey into Satanism - Forbidden History - S03 EP6 - History Documentary](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OdiNNLLMlVQ&pp=ygUIU2F0YW5pc20%3D)

Answer (score -1):

Based on Jesus's words to John in Revelation:

> I know thy works, that thou art neither cold, nor hot. **I would thou wert cold**, or hot. But because thou art lukewarm, and neither cold, not hot, I will begin to vomit thee out of my mouth. (Revelation 3:15-16 Douay-Rheims 1899 American edition)

This might sound strange, but Jesus, according to His own testimony, has an easier time dealing with pure evil (Satanists) than with neutrals (atheists). Evil in the long run causes less suffering to the evil man (possibly because it's self-limiting?) than the neutral man, like the atheist.