# What is the name for belief when a person believes that Devil exists but is not so sure about the God part?

Tags: demons, good-and-evil

This [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/what-is-more-objectionable-to-christians-satanism-or-atheism?newreg=92f4b0da53e94471a55615d94573b328)
got me thinking. I was an atheist gradually drifting into agnostic territory.

But once I got into my 40s, I came to the realization that the devil does exist in
many shapes and forms. Whether God exists or not I do not know and do not care so much.

But I know for sure you could not be really agnostic realizing that at least in part religion is useful at least to establish some framework of reference for good and evil.

This set of beliefs while non-Christian and might be off-topic in Christianity must have a name already. My question is what is it. I vaguely suspect that Christiantiy minus Christ is Judaism.

Comment: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Thanks, rephrased to, hopefully, be less self centered and more useful to the rest of the community.

Comment: This question is not a question about _comparative_ 'Christianity' (which is what this site is all about). It is merely expressing non-belief or unbelief or (as the answer makes clear) . . .  confusion. I suggest setting some time apart to go through the extensive archives (the purposed provision of the site) built up over the past twelve years and to reach some positive conclusions from the labours of the users over the years.

Comment: I suggest "Despair" as the appropriate label for the belief that nothing has the power to prevail over the power of evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is the name for belief when a person believes that Devil exists but is not so sure about the God part?**

The short answer is **confused**.

One can not accept the notion of **evil** without existence of **good**.

If one believes in the existence of the Devil, then the existence of God has to be understood. This is not a question of atheism, but of confusion.

The Devil is evil and God is good. One can not believe in the Devil and evil with the opposite being held not to exist.

Comment: So you are saying that in Christian terms the God is an alias for good.